# Does this code cause a violation of the one-definition rule?

Tags: c++, templates, friend, friend-function, one-definition-rule

I'm trying to work out under what circumstances the following code might cause a violation of the one-definition rule.

**header.h**

```cpp
#pragma once

#include <cstddef>

template<typename T, typename U>
class C {
 friend std::size_t f() {
  // Uses the template parameter that doesn't change
  return sizeof(T); 
 }

 friend std::size_t g() {
  // Uses the template parameter that does change
  return sizeof(U);
 }

 friend std::size_t h() {
  // Does not refer to template parameters
  return 0;
 }
};

// Declarations to help name lookup
std::size_t f();
std::size_t g();
std::size_t h();
```

**src1.cpp**

```cpp
#include "header.h"
// Cause definintion of f(), g() and h()
template class C<int, double>;
```

**src2.cpp**

```
#include "header.h"
// Cause definintion of f(), g() and h()
template class C<int, float>;
```

I've explicitly instantiated two different versions of the `C` class template in the two different translation units. If I link the translation units together, do I have ODR violations?

It seems obvious that there would be an ODR violation for `g()` because it has a different implementation in each translation unit.

But what about `f()` and `h()`?
The implementation (i.e. token stream) of each will remain unchanged between translation units. But they are both implicitly making use of different instantiations of `C`. Does that make a difference? There is no name-lookup happening here is there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A function that is defined as part of a friend declaration is implicitly an inline function, so there is no ODR violation as long as all of the definitions are the same in all translation units.  It is not a member of the class that it is a friend of, but is a global function, similar to declaring the function as a friend, then defining the inline function once the definition of the class is complete.

This is the case for `h`, which does not depend on any template parameter, and for `f`, which does depend on a template parameter but that parameter has the same type (`int`) in your example.

Function `g` has different definitions in the src1.cpp and src2.cpp, so this is a potential ODR violation.  This results in the program being ill-formed (no diagnostic required) *if* the function is ODR-used within both translation units.